# Grouping multiple columns with aggrgation and sum sql sever

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a table with 3 fields, EmpName, Request and AvgScore where 
EMPname is the concatenation of the name and surname, request is the number of requests the employee has been given and the AVGScore is their average score of the requests.
The following code snippet, does that for me.

```
SELECT     [Employee].surname + ', ' + [Employee].name AS EmpName, 
COUNT(DISTINCT [Request].ID) AS RequestNo, 
AVG([Answer]) / 4 AS AvgScore


FROM .....
```

(I haven't listed the joins and tables because it is too long winded)

```
GROUP BY [Ocean.Employee].surname + ', ' + [Ocean.Employee].name
```

My problem lies with the grouping of the table: 
I want to be able to group the table further, in which EMPName is descending, Request ASc and AvG descending and am unsure of how to present this in SQL Server.

I hope someone may be able to give me some assistance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's not grouping, that's `ORDER`.  Add:

`ORDER BY EmpName DESC, Request ASC, AvgScore DESC`